# Hexl-mode with colors?

Tags: font-lock, hexl-mode, coloring

I have just been using Hexl-mode to investigate some binary files.  What I would like though, is some way of highlighting the byte under consideration: at the moment the line and column indices are highlighted.  It would be very helpful if the intersection of that line and column could be highlighted with a color.  For example: the highlighted square in this picture have some color or background which distinguishes it from its surrounds:

[image: hexl-mode with current position highlighted]

Is there any way of doing this?

Note, I'm using:

`GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, X toolkit, Xaw3d scroll bars)
 of 2014-03-08 on lamiak, modified by Debian`

in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recomend you try `nhexl-mode` (install it from `M-x package-install` or `M-x package-list`).  It does do what you want.

This said, hexl-mode almost does what you want, since it places the cursor right in front of the byte you want highlighted.

Comment: Is the requested feature present in nhexl-mode out of the box, or does it require some configuration? Or was it just a general recommendation?

Comment: It's the way nhexl-mode works out of the box (because the cursor is in the right-hand-side text instead of the left-hand-side hex).